# Does $Pr^L_\kappa \in Pr^L$ behave like an "object classifier" or "universe"?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-topos-theory, locally-presentable-categories

Let $Pr^L$ denote the $\infty$-category of [presentable $\infty$-categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+presentable+%28infinity%2C1%29-category) and left adjoint functors. Let $Pr^L_\kappa \subset Pr^L$ denote the locally-full subcategory of [$\kappa$-compactly-generated $\infty$-categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/compactly+generated+%28%E2%88%9E%2C1%29-category) and left adjoints which preserve $\kappa$-compact objects (where $\kappa$ is some fixed regular cardinal). Note that in addition to being a *subcategory* of $Pr^L$, the $\infty$-category $Pr^L_\kappa$ is itself presentable, and so is naturally regarded as an *object* of $Pr^L$.

I would like to regard $Pr^L_\kappa \in Pr^L$ as an object which is analogous to an [object classifier](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%28sub%29object+classifier+in+an+%28infinity%2C1%29-topos) (a.k.a. "universe") $\mathcal U_\kappa$ in an $\infty$-topos $\mathcal E$. I'm not sure this is a "correct" intuition, so here are some questions which I hope will help sort out whether it is:

**Question 1:** What does the object $Pr^L_\kappa \in Pr^L$ represent?

That is, is there some snappy description of the hom-functor $Map_{Pr^L}(-, Pr^L_\kappa) : (Pr^L)^{op} \to SPACES$, or the 2-categorical hom-functor $Fun^L(-,Pr^L_\kappa) : (Pr^L)^{op} \to CAT$ or maybe the internal-hom functor $Fun^L(-, Pr^L_\kappa) :(Pr^L)^{op} \to Pr^L$? Ideally such a description would be along the lines of the functor represented by an object classifier, sending $\mathcal C \in Pr^L$ to some sort of size-restricted version of the slice $Pr^L/\mathcal C$ -- maybe with extra assumptions on $\kappa$ such as asking it to be strongly inaccessible.

**Question 2:** What does $Pr^L_\kappa \in Pr^L$ represent when restricted to $Pr^L_\kappa \subset Pr^L$?

That is, is there a nice description of the restricted hom-functor $Map_{Pr^L}(-,Pr^L_\kappa) : (Pr^L_\kappa)^{op} \to SPACES$, or of the 2-categorical or internal variants valued in $CAT$ or $Pr^L$?

Finally, observe that the $\infty$-category $Pr^L_\kappa$ (which is equivalent to the $\infty$-category $Rex_\kappa$ of small, idempotent-complete, $\kappa$-cocomplete categories and $\kappa$-cocontinuous functors) is itself $\kappa$-compactly-generated. So we may ask:

**Question 3:** What does $Pr^L_\kappa \in Pr^L_\kappa$ represent?

There are a few ways to make this precise. The functor $U$ "represented" by $Pr^L_\kappa$ might be taken to be any of the following:

1. $U = Map_{Pr^L_\kappa}(-,Pr^L_\kappa) : (Pr^L_\kappa)^{op} \to Spaces$
2. $U = Fun^{L,\kappa}(-,Pr^L_\kappa) : (Pr^L_\kappa)^{op} \to Cat$
3. $U = Ind_\kappa(Fun^{L,\kappa}(-,Pr^L_\kappa)) : (Pr^L)_\kappa^{op} \to CAT$
4. $U = Ind_\kappa(Fun^{L,\kappa}(-,Pr^L_\kappa)) : (Pr^L)_\kappa^{op} \to Pr^L_\kappa$
5. $U = Ind_\kappa(Fun^{L,\kappa}(-,Pr^L_\kappa)) : (Pr^L)_\kappa^{op} \to Pr^L$

Of these, (4) looks particularly attractive to me, since it's the "internal" version. But perhaps another option (or something else entirely!) is actually a better way to think about it!

Comment: I think the case of colimit preserving functors $C \to Pr^L$ has a nice fibrational description. I would say something like a "left and right adjoint bifibration $D \to C$ that satisfies a descent condition with respect to colimit in $C$" (using that colimit in $Pr^L$ are limits in $Pr^R$). So, it might be a good idea to start by figuring out this case in details and then see what happen when one adds the further condition to take values in $Pr^L_\kappa$ and to preserves $\kappa$-compact objects...

Comment: @SimonHenry Ah, I think you're right... A colimit-preserving functor $F : C \to Pr^L$ such that the composite $C \to Pr^L \to CAT$ preserves $\kappa$-filtered colimits for some $\kappa$ is exactly a presentable fibration, and [Gepner - Haugseng - Nikolaus](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.02161) show that in this case the Grothendieck construction $\int F$ of the functor is presentable, and the fibration $\int F \to C$ is an accessible functor. I don't think that $\int F \to C$ need be a left adjoint though, which is interesting -- we seem to get something _bigger_ than the slice...

Comment: Under the condition you have it is both left and right adjoint: taking each object to the initial or terminal object of the fibers gives both adjoint.

Comment: Oh of course... So it appears that $Pr^L$, if it lived in $Pr^L$, would classify precisely cocartesian fibrations in $Pr^L$ in the [usual 2-categorical sense](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/fibration+in+a+2-category). So $Pr^L_\kappa$ should definitely be some kind of "size-restricted fibration classifier".

Comment: Well, it's a bit more complicated than cocartesian fibration. I'm sure what the exact condition is, but you at least want bifibration with both adjoint, and you need a descent condition to express préservation of colimits.

Comment: @SimonHenry What I mean is, I believe the following are equivalent for a functor $\xi : X \to C$ with $C \in Pr^L$: (1) $\xi$ is a presentable fibration; (2) $\xi$ is the unstraightening of a functor $\Xi : C \to Pr^L$ which preserves colimits and and is "accessible" in the sense that $C \xrightarrow \Xi Pr^L \to CAT$ preserves $\kappa$-filtered colimits for some $\kappa$; (3) $\xi : X \to C$ is an opfibration in the 2-category $Pr^L$ in the sense that (i) $X \in \Pr^L$, (ii) $\xi$ preserves colimits and (iii) the functor $X \to (\xi \downarrow C)$ has a left adjoint _in $Pr^L/C$_.

Comment: @SimonHenry But now I think I see your point, and I am confused... I still want to say that (3) does imply that we have a bifibration in $CAT$, but I think you're right that the descent condition needs to be stated separately.